# Create Barcode from form data

Tags: javascript, pdf, barcode

I am trying to create a barcode within a PDF, so using javascript, that selects information from certain fields, and also would need an if statement.

I need to have the barcode numbers come from;
1. Call Number
2. Segment
3. If statement would come from the Associated Parts; if Yes needs to add a 999 on the end, if No, add a 000 on the end.

Help would be appreciated!

[Screen shot of PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77c7L.jpg)

This is one of my attempts;

```
var str1 = getField("Call Number").value;

var str2 = getField("Segment").value;

var res = str1.concat(str2);

if (Associated Parts = Yes) {
    add to event.value = "999";
} else {
    Add to event.value = "000";
}
```

This is what comes up when I just pick;

```
/* Customize: */
try
{
if ( app.viewerVersion >= ADBE.PMD_Need_Version )
    event.value = this.exportAsXFDFStr({aFields: ["Call Number", "Segment"], 
cHRef: ""});
else event.value = " ";
}
catch (e)
{
event.value = " ";
}
```

Comment: I haven't been able to create anything. I am stuck on just figuring it out at all. The PDF editor allows me to pick certain fields which would be fine if I did not need that IF statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JavaScript is quite a bit off. Without having the PDF in front of me, I think this is what you were getting at...

```
var str1 = this.getField("Call Number").value;
var str2 = this.getField("Segment").value;
var res = str1+str2;
if (this.getField("Associated Parts").value == "Yes") {
    event.value = res+"999";
} 
else {
    event.value = res+"000";
}
```

Your main problem was that the "if" wasn't comparing two values, it was using "=" (assignment) rather than "==" (logic).